# Linear algebra prove or disprove Kernel and Range

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

For a linear map $h: \mathbb R^3 \rightarrow \mathbb R^2$, the kernel of $h$ is a subspace of $ \mathbb R^2$.

For a linear map $h: \mathbb R^3 \rightarrow \mathbb R^2$, the range of $h$ is a subspace of $ \mathbb R^2$.

Can someone help me prove or disprove these statements. I'm pretty sure that the first one is false and the second one is true...

Comment: You are right in both acounts. Now just check **again** the definitions to make sure you fully understand and then you'll clearly see why you *obviously* are right.

Comment: You are correct that the first is false and the second is true, so the problem is coming up with *proofs*.  Do you know how to disprove a statement?  Maybe find an element in the kernel that is not an element of $\mathbb R^2$ (try the 0 in $\mathbb R^3$).  Do you know how to prove that a subset of $\mathbb R^2$ is a subspace?  There are axioms that you have to check, do you know what they are?

Comment: Actually, in the first case, the kernel is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$, not $\mathbb{R}^2$. The second assertion is correct.

Comment: Calculate the kernel and range of an example of such a map, and then you will understand the definitions.

Comment: If you got your answer to the question, I recommend you to tick it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Consider $h$ taking each element of $\mathbb R^3$ to $(0,0)$. Therefore, $Ker(h)=\mathbb R^3$ and is not a subspace of $\mathbb R^2$.
- Image of a linear map is always a subspace of the codomain.

These two are more than a hint and less than a solution but you had better check that in the first case $h$ is indeed a linear map and in the second one $Im(h)$ is as well.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, the kernel of $h$ must lie in the domain, not the codomain. However your wording is kind of unclear, because $\mathbb R^2$ (the codomain) can be viewed as a subspace of $\mathbb R^3$ (the domain).  Can you think of a map such that the kernel of $h$ is larger than all of $\mathbb R^2$?

Additionally, the range of $h$ must lie in the codomain, so certainly $\text{Im}\,h\subset\mathbb R^2$.  However, do you know that the range of $h$ is a subspace of the codomain?

Comment: $\mathbb{R}^2$ _cannot_ be viewed as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$, it is not even a _subset_. The most you can say is that there are subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^3$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: This seems overly pedantic for the circumstances.

Comment: I disagree. The question has a clear cut answer. $\mathbb{R}^2$ is _not_ a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ and that's that. There is nothing ambiguous. You may regard the line "$\mathbb{R}^2$ can be viewed as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$" in terms of isomorphism, but to the OP that's likely to induce the notion that $\mathbb{R}^2$ can be an actual subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$. It's unnecessary at best and wrong at worst.